# Breadcrumbs are different on localhost

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, breadcrumbs

I created 1:1 copy of Magento 1.9.1 on localhost for development purposes. Everything works fine, but the breadcrumbs are missing category trail:

[image: Original on the left]

Hosting environment on the left, localhost on the right.
Category "ODKURZACZE" is missing.

What is the reason and how can I solve it?

Comment: get yourself database copy too

Comment: I uploaded full database copy

Comment: In this case @MTM is right. You can see those breadcrumbs only if you navigate to product through categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Category link doesn't show in breadcrumb if the product is accessed with a direct link, breadcrumb only add category if you navigate to product through category.

Comment: Tried in incognito mode and nothing has changed. On localhost, navigation through category didn't add category trail. On hosting, opening direct link didn't remove category trail.

Comment: Ok, tried in different browser and the behavior is exactly as you said.